# Nodejs can't update index in an array in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to make an api for a bus ticketing sistem, but I can't seem to get an how to make it work in nodejs

```
[
 {
  "id":1,
  "hour" : "7:30am"
  , "seats" : [
            0 ,
   0, 0, 0, 0 ,
   0, 0, 0, 0 ,
   0, 0, 0, 0 ,
   0, 0, 0, 0 ,
   0, 0, 0, 0 ,
   0, 0, 0, 0 ,
   0, 0, 0 ,0, 0
 ]
},
{
"id":2,
"hour" : "9:00am",
"seats" : [
            0 ,
   0, 0, 0, 0 ,
   0, 0, 0, 0 ,
   0, 0, 0, 0 ,
   0, 0, 0, 0 ,
   0, 0, 0, 0 ,
   0, 0, 0, 0 ,
   0, 0, 0 ,0, 0
 ]
}
```

This is my mongodb query

```
db.schedules.update({"id":2}, {"$set" : {"seats.8" : "1"}});
```

and everything seems to work just fine until I try it on nodejs

```
router.put('/reserve/:id/:seat', function(req, res, next) {
  schedules.update({"id": req.params.id}, { "$set":{ "seats." + req.params.seat+: "1"}}, function(err, doc) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(400).json({"error"});
    }
    if (doc.result.nModified) {
      res.status(200).json({"status": "ok"});
    } else {
      res.status(400).json({"error": "The seat hasn't been reserved"});
    }
  });
```

this is the error returned:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token +

I have tried multiple ways and can't get that working

Comment: You just have some typos. Should be `req.params.seat: "1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have invalid javascript syntax here: `schedules.update({"id": req.params.id}, { "$set":{ "seats." + req.params.seat+: "1"}}` Can't concat a string in an object definition.

Try like this, using a property reference notation (that will create the property):

```
let updateObj = { $set: {} }
updateObject.$set['seats.' + req.params.seat] = '1'
schedules.update({"id": req.params.id}, updateObj, function ... )
```

Comment: thank you! It worked, I'm a noob with nodejs and javascript and general.

Comment: What about template strings? { $set: { `seats.${req.params.seat}`:  '1' }}

Comment: @alexmac You might wanna escape the backticks for formatting